# How to design this component in Android app that appears like a Spinner but not actually?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-spinner

I have could just simply design a list drop-down spinner ( when onclick on such spinner, a drop-down list appear) - however, what I want is when I click on such component the outcome is exactly like in the **BELOW image**), what happened next is shown in the below image - a blur search frame appears for some options. As the drop-down is so troublesome with a long list.

My opinion, I think that such component should be another component in Android app - not Spinner or there is a Spinner mode that I have not discovered?

I am looking forward to all of your advice or documentation!

**Expected result**
  [image]

Comment: You can use dialog with custom interface and list view adapter .

Comment: You can also  autocompleteview or spinner with custom layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your spinner to open as a dialog, you can do so by simply setting the `spinnerMode` to "dialog" in the xml.

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
```

Now, if you wanted to customize the layout,  You could create your own custom layout and use that for the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by AutoCompleteTextView with custom adapter.

Find reference below :
 [Android AutocompleteTextView with custom adapter example](https://www.androidcode.ninja/android-autocompletetextview-custom-arrayadapter-sqlite/)